# OCaml - Why does this declaration work when not associated with a variable name?

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that takes a tuple as a parameter and returns true if the second member of the tuple is equal to 1, 2, or 3.
Doing this works just fine by returning the type that I expect:

```
# fun (x, y) -> match (x, y) with
      | (x, (1 | 2 | 3)) -> true
      | (x, _) -> false;;
- : 'a * int -> bool = <fun>
```

I want to be able to actually test the function by binding it to a variable, but I get a syntax error where `try` is underlined:

```
# let try = fun (x, y) -> match (x, y) with
    | (x, (1 | 2 | 3)) -> true
    | (x, _) -> false;;
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` is a keyword used in exception-handling. You'll need to pick another name for your function.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that! `test` it'll be then!